# ExtJS, How to prevent window from being maximized

Tags: javascript, extjs6, maximize-window

I have an ExtJS window component with maximize/minimize toggling button( top-right corner near the close button ).

I am trying to disable (or cancel) window maximizing functionality for some conditions.

Usually, most of the events have a preceding one with the `before` prefix (e.g. `show` and `beforeshow`) which provides ability to stop execution immediately by returning `false` from the handler function.

Unfortunately, this approach is not applicable for `maximize` event of `Ext.window.Window` component because there is no `beforemaximize` event.

Is there any other way to prevent maximizing the window?

This is a configuration of Window's view and [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38lt) is a live example in fidde.

```js
Ext.define('App.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    layout: 'anchor',
    maximizable: true,
    maxWidth: 300,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    controller: 'myapp',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'myapp'
    },
    listeners: {
        maximize: 'onMaximize',
        restore: 'onMinimize'
    },
    bind: {
        title: '{test}'
    },
    defaults: {
        labelWidth: 40,
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text : 'Toggle Window Maximize Ability',
            handler: 'onToggleMaximizeAbility'
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Field 2'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textarea',
            anchor: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'HTML'
        }];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe, not the best way but you could give and id to the window like `'winTest'` and at the `onMaximize` function you can manage this. `var isMaxWinAllowed = this.getViewModel().get('isMaxWinAllowed');
        if (!isMaxWinAllowed){
            Ext.getCmp('winTest').toggleMaximize();
        }`    https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38md

Comment: @MuzafferGalata This solution works fine for a custom button, but not with the default ExtJS `maximize` button in the top right corner next to the close button. In my example, the `Toggle Window Maximize Ability` button is only required to toggle a flag that should determine whether the window _can be_ maximized/minimized using the usual controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

This option overrides the [`Ext.window.Window:toggleMaximize`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-toggleMaximize) method, [as seen here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/38mq)... just click the "Toggle Maximize Override" button.  In this version, I added the `toggleMaxmize` override in MainView.js:

```
toggleMaximize: function() {
    if (this.getViewModel().get('isMaxWinAllowed')) {
        return this.callParent();
    }
    this.getController().showToast('Cannot Maximize!');
}
```

**Option 2:**

Add binding to the maximize button.  In the same Fiddle as above, you click the "Maximize Button Binding" button.  In this version, I tap into the view's `afterrender` event and add binding for the maximize button:

```
var maximizeButton = view.down('[type="maximize"]')
if (maximizeButton) {
    maximizeButton.setBind({
        disabled: '{!isMaxWinAllowed}'
    });
}
```

Comment: Solution #1 is workable, but the maximize button does not reflect changing of `isMaxWinAllowed` flag. The option 2 ( bind maximize button's disable ) is more preferable in my case. However, I'm not sure if it's safe enough to override the private `addTools` method. Could this idea be implemented differently?

Comment: I think it's safe enough... obviously any method can change in the framework, but I don't see a problem with overriding it.  If you don't want to do that, there're several other ways of going about it... one way is to grab the reference of the maximize tool and make your changes after the framework has created it.  You can grab the reference by something like `Ext.getCmp('window-1009').down('[type="maximize"]')`.  Obviously you'll want to make it more specific and change it accordingly.

Comment: The reference to the maximize tool is more flexible for implementation... Obviously, I can create a new bindable flag-property in my MainView.js , override corresponding setter method for changing maximize tool availability inside it using incoming value. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: I've gone and updated my answer to include both options.  Hope that helps!

Comment: I think that 2nd option is the best solution for this issue! Thank you so much for updating your answer!